# How to execute llvm-ir in java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir, graalvm

I have written a compiler in java which can output llvm-ir. Now I would like to actually run the compiler somehow. I've read about GraalVM and how it should be possible to run other languages which use LLVM inside of java, however, I couldn't find out how to run llvm-ir itself with it. I don't have to use GraalVM though, any suggested approach would be fine as long as it enables me to somehow execute that code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to get yourself a GraalVM, and you can execute your LLVM bitcode file with

```
lli [LLI options] [GraalVM options] [polyglot options] <bitcode file> [program args]
```

as per
https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/llvm/

The `lli` launcher lives in the `bin` folder of the graalvm distribution.

Regarding the format of the bitcode file the docs on https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/llvm/Compiling/ say

> While the
> GraalVM LLVM runtime can execute plain bitcode files, the preferred
> format is a native executable with embedded bitcode. The executable
> file formats differ on Linux and macOS. Linux by default uses ELF
> files. The bitcode is stored in a section called .llvmbc. The macOS
> platform uses Mach-O files. The bitcode is in the __bundle section of
> the __LLVM segment.